# How to translate qt key press event to osg event?

Tags: qt, openscenegraph

In my osg Eventhandler, I have the following code

```
if(ea.getModKeyMask() & osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::MODKEY_SHIFT){
   do something
}
```

ea is the `osgGA::GUIEventAdapter`. In the osgwidget the keypress event is handled by

```
void OSGWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
QString keyString = event->text();
const char *keyData = keyString.toLocal8Bit().data();
this->getEventQueue()->keyPress(osgGA::GUIEventAdapter::KeySymbol(*keyData));
}
```

However, when I run my code, it seems the osgGA::GUIEventAdapter can't capture the shift key press event. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

"SHIFT" key is a modifier key.

And your `event->text()` returns an empty string, when you ask for SHIFT key press.

Try below said way to handle SHIFT key...

```
if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier)
{
    //SET SHIFT KEY TO OPENSCENEGRAPH
}
```